# DXL - Regex for matches() that only matches whole word

Tags: regex, ibm-doors

I am using dxl and I have two strings where string a is a new line separated collection of IDs and string b is a specific ID I am looking for in string a.

Bad Case:

string a = "ID12\nID2\nID3"

string b = "ID1"

matches(b,a) will incorrectly return true in this case when I want it to return false as there is no exact "ID1" id. What is the proper regex DXL will support such that for this bad case that it returns false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string a = "ID12\nID2\nID3"

string b = "^ID1$"

print matches(b,a)
```

The above will correctly return false - for your specific example, you need to assert that ID1 is the full string from start (^) to end ($) of line.

There is no MULTILINE flag in DXL regular expressions; \A and \Z are not valid control characters for DXL.

Answer (score 1):

Use start and end anchors:

```
\AID1\Z
```

These anchors are different from `^` and `$`, which will also match start and end of *line* when `MULTILINE` flag is used.

Comment: Creating a regular expression:

Regexp b = regexp2 "\AID1\Z"

I am reeiving a "badly formed token" error.

Comment: @Cgrillo try escaping the backslashes with backslashes